# Components are appended to the top of the page

Tags: angular, routes

This problem appears when I started consuming a REST API within an angular component
For every route that i'm navigating to, the component is being appended to the top of the page while the desired behaviour is that components should be swapped.

After lots of search I tried to narrow it down to this : 
when the REST API is not sending any data (there is no data from subscribe call within the service ) I noticed that the routing is working perfectly 
However ,as soon as the data start coming (asynchronously ) the case I described lately starts appearing

I really don't know what to do and I don't Know Whats causing the problem 
I tried to use the same analogy when consuming and declaring the API , and It is geeting the data I want , but this weird pbm whith routing I couldn't solve

this is a part of my routing code :

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(BillsRoutes),
......
    providers: [/*BillService*/]
})
export class BillsModule {
}
```

bills.routing.ts:

```
export const BillsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [ {
            path: '',
            component: BillsComponent
        }]
    }];
```

app.routing.ts:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    }, {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [ 
{.....}, {
                 path: 'bills',
                 loadChildren: './Bills/bills.module#BillsModule'
             }
        ]
```

app.module.ts:

```
export class MaterialModule {}

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        CommonModule,
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
...]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide a component here

```
export const BillsRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', component: AddedComponent
    children: [ {
        path: '',
        component: BillsComponent
    }]
}];
```

or use this

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'bills', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'bills', component: BillsComponent},
```

or

```
{ path: '', component: BillsComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Comment: I tried this but , still did not solve the problem 
what about the """ loadChildren: './Bills/bills.module#BillsModule'  """
? how should I change it to go with your answer?

Comment: i prefer if you change your second route to this,  path: 'admin',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [

Comment: component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            },
{
                     path: 'bills',
                     loadChildren: './Bills/bills.module#BillsModule'
                 }]

If switch that I would be forced to add that component to the main module , and It's not right , the logic of the existing routing is it's loading the routes for each Module's relative path